# Issue with url rewriting on a zues web server

Tags: php, url-rewriting

**Background**

I have been working on a simple content management system for a client that allows them to manage news articles for their mobile application. Now the system was written on a local development server running LAMP with php version 5.

Now my client is using a completely different platform (Zues web server) that their hosting provider has supplied them (I say completely different because I have no prior knowledge of the system before now, they may not be that much different but to me it feels that way) After my first attempt to migrate the system to their server I came across a few issues, the first one being they where running php version 4, I managed to convince them to upgrade to php 5 which they have now done.

But another issue I have come across is the way Zues handles scripts, where as Apache has a .htaccess file that allows you to do a plethora of things, Zues seems to prefer using separate script files for things such as url rewriting.

-

**Issue**

So my issue is that I am unsure how to properly rewrite a set of .htaccess url-rewriting rules to properly work with Zues, following a few tutorials (It's hard to find decent in depth tutorials for zues, or at least it has been for me) I have a basic rewrite.script which works for some pages but not all.

In my application there are two main sections that aren't working, both sections are almost identical other than the mysql queries and a few different elements in the forms, so I'll just talk about one, the news section.

A user can click on the news section which will then check if the user has specified a page number they want to view. if they haven't it will set one for them by redirecting them to `/news/1/` there is also 2 sections when a user views the news section, published and unpublished news, when a user clicks the area they want to visit the url will be set to `/news/published` or `news/unpublished` the page will then set this value to a session variable and reset the page to `/news/1/`

And this seems to be where my problem is, I'm thinking that it has something to do with the regex for the pages becasue no matter which page i goto within news it is setting the pages url to `news/1/` and then firefox is returning the error:

```
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
```

So my main guess is that instead of redirecting say `/news/create/` to `news_create.php` it is redirecting it to the `news_view.php` page, but even if this is the case I still don't understand why on an apache server it loads fine and on Zues it is returning that error.

Does anyone know what I've done wrong and what I need to change to fix it?

-

**Code**

*original .htaccess*

```
#Enable URL rewriting.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^dashboard/?$ dashboard.php [L]

RewriteRule ^account/login/?$ account_login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^account/logout/?$ account_logout.php [L]
RewriteRule ^account/settings/?$ account_settings.php [L]
RewriteRule ^account/retrieve/?$ account_retrieve.php [L]
RewriteRule ^account/retrieve/([A-Z0-9_]+)/?$ account_retrieve.php?recovery_code=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^news/?$ news_view.php [L]
RewriteRule ^news/create/?$ news_create.php [L]
RewriteRule ^news/modify/?$ news_modify.php [L]
RewriteRule ^news/modify/([0-9]+)/?$ news_modify.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/delete/([0-9]+)/?$ news_view.php?delete=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/([a-z]+)/?$ news_view.php?view=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/?$ news_view.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^information/?$ information_view.php [L]
RewriteRule ^information/create/?$ information_create.php [L]
RewriteRule ^information/categories/?$ information_categories.php [L]
RewriteRule ^information/modify/?$ information_modify.php [L]
RewriteRule ^information/modify/([0-9]+)/?$ information_modify.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^information/delete/([0-9]+)/?$ information_view.php?delete=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^information/([a-z]+)/?$ information_view.php?view=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^information/([0-9]+)/?$ information_view.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^json/get/([a-z]+)/?$ json_call.php?get_article_type=$1 [L]
```

*new rewrite.script*

```
match URL into $ with ^/dashboard/
if matched 
    set URL=/dashboard.php
    goto END
endif





match URL into $ with ^/account/login/
if matched 
    set URL=/account_login.php
    goto END
endif

match URL into $ with ^/account/logout/
if matched 
    set URL=/account_logout.php
    goto END
endif

match URL into $ with ^/account/settings/
if matched 
    set URL=/account_settings.php
    goto END
endif

match URL into $ with ^/account/retrieve/
if matched 
    set URL=/account_retrieve.php
    goto END
endif

match URL into $ with ^/account/retrieve/([A-Z0-9_]+)/
if matched 
    set URL=/account_retrieve.php?recovery_code=$1
    goto END
endif





match URL into $ with ^/news/
if matched 
    set URL=/news_view.php
    goto END
endif

match URL into $ with ^/news/create/
if matched 
    set URL=/news_create.php
    goto END
endif

match URL into $ with ^/news/modify/
if matched 
    set URL=/news_modify.php
    goto END
endif

match URL into $ with ^/news/modify/([0-9]+)/
if matched 
    set URL=/news_modify.php?id=$1
    goto END
endif

match URL into $ with ^/news/delete/([0-9]+)/
if matched 
    set URL=/news_view.php?delete=$1
    goto END
endif

match URL into $ with ^/news/([a-z]+)/
if matched 
    set URL=/news_view.php?view=$1
    goto END
endif

match URL into $ with ^/news/([0-9]+)/
if matched 
    set URL=/news_view.php?page=$1
    goto END
endif





match URL into $ with ^/information/
if matched 
    set URL=/information_view.php
    goto END
endif

match URL into $ with ^/information/create/
if matched 
    set URL=/information_create.php
    goto END
endif

match URL into $ with ^/information/categories/
if matched 
    set URL=/information_categories.php
    goto END
endif

match URL into $ with ^/information/modify/
if matched 
    set URL=/information_modify.php
    goto END
endif

match URL into $ with ^/information/modify/([0-9]+)/
if matched 
    set URL=/information_modify.php?id=$1
    goto END
endif

match URL into $ with ^/information/delete/([0-9]+)/
if matched 
    set URL=/information_view.php?delete=$1
    goto END
endif

match URL into $ with ^/information/([a-z]+)/
if matched 
    set URL=/information_view.php?view=$1
    goto END
endif

match URL into $ with ^/information/([0-9]+)/
if matched 
    set URL=/information_view.php?page=$1
    goto END
endif





match URL into $ with ^/json/get/([a-z]+)/
if matched 
    set URL=/json_call.php?get_article_type=$1
    goto END
endif
```

*Related Code from news_view.php*

```
<?php

    //Require the configuration file.
    require('_configuration.php');

    //Establish a database connection.
    $connection->establish();

    //Check that the user is logged in.
    $account->check_login_state();

    //Check what view is selected and assign a view.
    if($_GET['view']) {
        if($_GET['view'] == 'pending') {
            $_SESSION[$G_instance_name]['view']['news'] = 'pending';
            header('location: /news/');
            die;
        } else {
            $_SESSION[$G_instance_name]['view']['news'] = 'published';
            header('location: /news/');
            die;
        }
    } else if(!isset($_SESSION[$G_instance_name]['view']['news']) or empty($_SESSION[$G_instance_name]['view']['news'])) {
        $_SESSION[$G_instance_name]['view']['news'] = 'published';
        header('location: /news/');
        die;
    }

    //Check if the modify article is still set and unset it.
    if(!empty($_SESSION[$G_instance_name]['modify']['news'])) {
        unset($_SESSION[$G_instance_name]['modify']['news']);
    }

    //Check if the user has attempted to delete an article.
    if(isset($_GET['delete'])) {
        $operation->article->delete($_GET['delete']);
    }

    //Check if the user is on a page, if note set the page to 1 as default.
    if(!isset($_GET['page']) or empty($_GET['page'])) {
        header('location: /news/1/');
        die;
    }

    //Get all news articles.
    $news_article = $operation->pagition->gather_article_data('news');

?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I was missing an `$` at the end of each match line.

```
match URL into $ with ^/account/login/
```

should of been

```
match URL into $ with ^/account/login/$
```